# Self-convolution of an $L^2$-function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L^2([S^1])$ (where $S^1$ is the circle, viewed as $[0,1]$ with endpoints identified) and define $f^n$ be the $n$-fold convolution of $f$ with itself. Let $|-|_1$ be the $L^1$-norm. I want to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (||f^n||_1)^{1/n} = ||\hat{f}||_{\infty} = \text{max }_{n< \infty}|\hat{f}(n)|$$ where $\hat{f}(n)$ is the $n$th Fourier coefficients of $f.$

I can easily show that $$||\hat{f}||_\infty \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} (||f^n||_1)^{1/n}$$ but the other direction is more tricky. There is a hint which says that one should use $||f^n||_1 = \int f^n [exp(i \cdot arg(f^n))]^\ast$ but I am at loss. Any hints or arguments would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint, we have that
$$
\|f^n\|_1 = \langle e^{i\varphi_n} , f^n \rangle_{L^2}=\langle g, \widehat{f}^n\rangle_{\ell^2} .
$$
Here, $g\in\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ is (the Fourier transform of $e^{i\varphi_n}$ and) an element of norm $1$, and $\widehat{f}^n$ is a genuine $n$th power. Thus, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
\|f^n\|_1^{1/n} \le \|\widehat{f}\|_{2n} ,
$$
and we obtain the other inequality from the fact that if $a\in\ell^p$ for some $p<\infty$, then $\lim_{p\to\infty} \|a\|_p=\|a\|_{\infty}$ (justifying the notation).

This is easy to prove (and will be in many texts). We can assume that $\|a\|_{\infty}=1$. Then
$$
\sum_{|a_n|<1} |a_n|^p \to 0
$$
by dominated convergence, so
$$
1 \le \sum |a_n|^p \le C
$$
for all large $p$.